# Not able to create mysql datasource in Jboss 7.1.1

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jboss

I am using `jboss as 7.1.1 final` release. I am trying to add `mysql driver` to the server via the admin console. I am able to do so but when I go to create the datasources, I do not find the driver listed there. I followed the steps to add the driver to the server as mentioned in this link :
http://www.appeon.com/support/documents/appeon_online_help/1.5/server_configuration_guide_for_j2ee/ch03s03s03.html#d0e4128

I followed from step 3 of Installing a JDBC driver via the Web console as I had already created one management user.To summarize what I did,

1. I added a driver file `E:\DevSoftwares\servers\jboss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\com\mysql\main\META-INF\services\java.sql.Driver` and its content as following : `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource`(fully qualified driver class name).
2. create module.xml file inside `E:\DevSoftwares\servers\jboss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\com\mysql\main\` and its content as below :
3. Added `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` file inside `E:\DevSoftwares\servers\jboss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\com\mysql\main\`
4. Ran `jar -uf mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` `META-INF\services\java.sql.Driver` command to modify the jar. 
   After running this command I could see a `services\java.sql.Driver` file with driver class name as given in step 1 inside META-INF folder of the jar file which was not there before running the command.

I picked up the fully qualified name of the driver class for mysql for Jboss 7.x from below link : 
http://www.appeon.com/support/documents/appeon_online_help/1.5/server_configuration_guide_for_j2ee/ch03s03s07.html#d0e5769

I was able to figure out what is causing the problem, when I try to enable the deployed jar I get an exception in the server console stating : unable to instantiate driver class `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource` :

> java/lang.ClassCastException :
>   com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource.

However I checked the `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` and was able to find the driver class mentioned above in the same directory structure as the classes fully qualified name.

I am not able to figure out why I am getting this exception or what I am doing wrong during the setup that is causing this issue.The platform I am using is windows. Could some one please help me with it.

NOTE : the content of `module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">
  <resources>
     <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
     <module name="javax.api"/>
     <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
 </module>`
```

Comment: Start by using the latest version of the JDBC driver which is up to now 5.1.39, indeed 5.1 is the recommended version as you can see here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-versions.html

Comment: what about your datasource config?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I tried with the latest version i.e 5.1.39. Now I am able to see the jar while trying to create datasource but when I am testing the connection I am getting error stating connection is not valid. However I tried with the same connection string and user name , password via java code and was able to connect, which indicates that the connection information is correct.

Comment: also the driver class name in this case was different then the one given in the link mentioned above. Its com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver instead of com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource. When I try to modify the jar like I did in my question and try to deploy and enable this version of the jar I get the same classcastexception.

Answer (score 1):

Please check that you have added your MySQL datasource configuration in `standalone.xml` or in equivalent XML file:-

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                <driver>h2</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlExampleDS" pool-name="MySqlExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jboss7db</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <pool>
                    <max-pool-size>30</max-pool-size>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>root</user-name>
                    <password>admin</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: don't I need to do this step if I am setting up data source via configuration file, in my case I am setting it up using the admin console  UI interface, which I assume will create this part in standalone.xml once the whole operation is completed ?

Comment: yes the admin UI will create the above for you. You will however need to create the com.mysql module yourself, eg download the drivers and create the module.xml and put in the modules directory structure. many online examples on how to do that.